# jquery DataTables Reload without page refresh

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, datatable, asp.net-web-api2

I am using [jQuery DataTables](https://www.datatables.net/) and here is what my table currently looks like:

[image]

Now, as of right now when I click `Deactivate` I am using ajax to call my WebApi method to set that record to `active = false`.. so the checkbox in the table should be unchecked.

```
public IHttpActionResult Deletecode_AutoMake(int id)
{
    code_AutoMake code_AutoMake = db.code_AutoMake.Find(id);
    if (code_AutoMake == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    code_AutoMake.Active = false;
    db.Entry(code_AutoMake).State = EntityState.Modified;
    db.SaveChanges();

    return Ok(code_AutoMake);
}
```

This all works as expected.. but the table doesn't reload, unless if I refresh the page to see the check box actually unchecked.

Here is how my DataTable is set up.

```
$("#Auto-Make-Table").on("click",
    ".js-automake-delete",
    function () {

        var link = $(this);
        var autoMakeName = $(this).data("automake-name");
        var autoMakeId = $(this).data("automake-id");

        bootbox.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this auto make?",
            function (result) {
                if (result) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: infoGetUrl + autoMakeId,
                        method: "DELETE",
                        success: function () {
                            autoMakeTable.reload();
                            toastr.success(autoMakeName + " successfully deleted");
                        },
                        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            var status = capitalizeFirstLetter(textStatus);
                            var error = $.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText);
                            console.log(error);
                            toastr.error(status + " - " + error.exceptionMessage);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
    });
```

My question/goal is.. how do I get the table to refresh/reload itself without an actual page refresh?

Any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE**

Tried using `autoMakeTable.ajax.reload();`

Received this error:

[image]

Followed by this one:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose your datatable is assigned like this,

```
var myDataTable = $('#myTableId').DataTable({
  //Rest code
 })
```

Then inside your `success method` for deactivate, you just need to reload your datatable like this,

```
 success: function()
 {
  myDataTable.ajax.reload();
  //rest code
 }
```

You forgot to add **ajax**. Please check this [official link](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload()) to learn more.

**UPDATED:**

If your partial view is `strongly typed`, then call your action method in success method and render it, like, In your above success method,

```
success: function()
 { 
   $.ajax({ 
       url: "@Url.Action("Index", "code_AutoMake")", //As you have mentioned in the chat
       method: "GET",
       success: function (data) 
        { 
         //Here just render that partial view like 
         $("#myDiv").html('').html(data); //This will empty first then render the new data
        }
      })
```

**Note:** Here **myDiv** is the `id` of `div`, where your table located.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I believe, you are binding your datatable by using **Ajax**. And you need to write your datatable name instead **myDataTable**. I think your datatable variable name is **autoMakeTable**. So u need to write `autoMakeTable.ajax.reload();` inside success method.

Comment: Sorry, I did do that.. I just copy and pasted your code.. but I did use my personal table name `autoMakeTable`.. and received those errors

Comment: Is your datatable get action method returning data in `json format` or you simply returning a view ?

Comment: I'm confused.. why does my Get method matter, if the page doesn't refresh?

Comment: Yes! If you dont want to refresh a page and want to load data then you need to return data in `json` or  `xml` format. The error itself saying that your json data is invalid.

Comment: So shouldn't I be returning data in json or xml in my `PUT` method, since that is the method I am calling to deactivate a record?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149618/discussion-between-basanta-matia-and-bville-kid).

Comment: have a look at : https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1191769/Beginners-Guide-for-implementing-AJAX-CRUD-Operati

Answer (score 0):

Create in your php file, or which file it may be, a table with the same html structure as your current one, but than with new data that you have received by doing the ajax call.

```
$.post( "newTable.php", function( data ) {
     $( ".currentTable" ).html( data );
});
```

Comment: You can view the Example here: https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/38969/reload-refresh-table-after-event